# How to subtract values from one array with another ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array like below and I want to subtract one set from another set.

```
values1 = [[6336.94, 0, 0, 0], [3613.12, 0, 0, 0], [2862.95, 0, 0, 0]]


values2 = [[-842.68, 0, 0, 0], [-184.25, 0, 0, 0], [-112.18, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I want to get a final array like this:

```
[[7179.62,0,0,0],[3797.37,0,0,0],[2975.13,0,0,0]]
```

I have tried `values1.zip(values2).map {|x,y| x-y}` but it returns me with an array with first one and zero's removed.

Comment: `values1.flatten.zip(values2.flatten).map { |a,b| a - b }.each_slice(4).to_a`

Comment: Definitely not an optimal solution though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.zip` only looks one level down. In your example x and y are not the values in the internal arrays, they're the internal arrays themselves. Subtracting one array from another removes all common elements from the first. That's why the result you see is first array with all zeros (common elements) removed.

If you want to zip the internal arrays, you need to go one level deeper:

```
values1.zip(values2).map { |x, y| x.zip(y).map { |a, b| a - b } }
```

Comment: Worked like a charm :) . I didn't thought of that. Thank you.